# Is $xz+1 $ a proper divisor of $a_3z^3+a_2z^2+a_1z+1$ finitely often?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given a polynomial $P=a_3z^3+a_2z^2+a_1z+1, z >0$ with non-negative integer coefficients $a_1, a_2, a_3\ne 0$, it appears if $P$ is **not** factorizable then there are **finitely** many positive integers $x, z$ such that $xz+1 \mid P(z)$, $xz+1<P(z)$. If $a_2=a_1=0$, the claim is true. [The Diophantine equation $ (xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{3}+1$ has no solutions in positive integers with $z > a^2+2a$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386989/the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-az31-has-no-solutions-in-positive-i). However the proof for the general case doesn't follow directly from the proof for the case $P=a_3z^3+1$. Also for a particular triple $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$, what's the minimum value of $z$ such that $xz+1$ is not a proper divisor of  $P(z)$ for all $x>1$?

My thoughts:
If $P$ is factorizable then we can find integers $b_1, b_2, b_3$ such that $a_3z^3+a_2z^2+a_1z+1=(b_1z+1)(b_2z^2+b_3z+1)$. Expanding and comparing coefficients we get $b_1+b_3=a_1$, $b_1b_3+b_2=a_2$, and $b_1b_2=a_3$. Since $P$ is assumed non-factorizable, we will have to use this result somewhere in the proof.

Comment: Can the minimum value of $z$ as described in the question be given as a function of $a_3, a_2,$ and $a_1$?

Comment: Why do you want to prove that and how do you know it's true?

Comment: Questions in the imperative voice ("Prove that …") are usually not well received; I would suggest editing it.  I'm also pretty sure that you mean that there are *only* finitely many such integers. \\ Also, TeX note: using `|` with manual spacing doesn't work well; prefer `\mid`. Compare, for example, the spacing of $a \not | \ b$ `a \not | \ b` to $a \nmid b$ `a \nmid b`.  I have edited accordingly (but not to make the other changes I suggested).

Comment: Because it has application to primality testing. If this is true which is most likely the case beyond doubt then if $z$ is prime, we can prove whether $P(z)$ is prime by checking if $b^{P(z) - 1} \equiv 1 ($mod $P(z))$ and $b^{(P(z) - 1) /p} \not\equiv 1 ($mod $P(z)) $. There would be no need to obtain another factor of $P(z) - 1$ required in Pocklington's test

Comment: It's most likely true because I have examined a number of cases by experiment . Also I already proved the case when $a_2=a_1=0$  which gives me more confidence

Comment: @LSpice, I have made some changes. I am new to Tex. Feel free to edit it so as to make it more clear as long as the meaning is not altered

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you're asking.  You always have $P(z) = x z + 1$ where $x = a_3 z^2 + a_2 z + a_1$.  That makes infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Have you opened the link in the question. Perhaps it could give more context to the question. I would like to prove that the Diophantine equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=a_3z^3 +a_2z^2+a_1z+1$ has finitely many solutions in positive integers $x, y, z$ if the polynomial $a_3z^3 +a_2z^2+a_1z+1$ can not be factorized for instance $z^3+1=(z+1)(z^2 - z+1)$ whereas $z^3+z+1$ can not be factorized.

Comment: @DavidJones: Robert Israel pointed out that the title question is not what you are interested in. You want to show that $xz+1$ is a proper divisor of $a_3z^3 +a_2z^2+a_1z+1$ only finitely often.

Comment: Yes that's right. I want to show that there's a positive integer $z_{min} $ such that for all $z>z_{min} $,  $xz+1 \not  |  \ P(z) $ for all $x>0$

Comment: Am an engineering student, not so good at bringing out what I want to say clearly. If the question can be edited for more clarity, that would be good

Comment: @DavidJones That statement is false, as Robert says. For any $z$ we have $xz+1\mid P(z)$ for $x=a_3 z^2 + a_2 z + a_1$, and $x>0$ if $z>0$ (since $a_i>0$).

Comment: Now I get. I am looking for a proper divisor i.e $xz+1<P(z)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conjecture is true. That is, if the integral cubic polynomial
$$P(Z)=a_3 Z^3+a_2 Z^2+a_1 Z+1$$
is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[Z]$ (hence also in $\mathbb{Q}[Z]$ by [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial))), then there are only finitely many positive integer solutions of the equation
$$(xz+1)(yz+1)=P(z).$$

**1.** First we consider the case when $x\mid a_3$ or $y\mid a_3$. By symmetry, it suffices to deal with the case $x\mid a_3$. We fix $x$ for this section. By long division, we get an integral quadratic polynomial $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[Z]$ and a nonzero integer $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$a_3^2 P(Z)=(xZ+1)Q(Z)+r.$$
If $xz+1\mid P(z)$, then $xz+1\mid r$, hence there are finitely many possibilities for $z$ (and also for $y$).

**2.** Now we consider the case when $x\nmid a_3$ and $y\nmid a_3$. We rewrite the original equation as
$$tz=x+y-a_1\qquad\text{where}\qquad t:=a_3z+a_2-xy.$$
Here $t$ is an integer. If $t\leq 0$, then $x+y\leq a_1$, which leads to finitely many triples $(x,y,z)$. So let us focus on the case $t>0$. We use an identity inspired by the OP's earlier post:
\begin{align*}
(tx-a_3)(ty-a_3)&=t^2 xy-a_3 t(x+y)+a_3^2\\
&=t^2(a_3z+a_2-t)-a_3 t(tz+a_1)+a_3^2\\
&=-t^3+a_2 t^2-a_1 a_3 t+a_3^2.
\end{align*}
We conclude that $t\leq 3\max(|a_1|,|a_2|,|a_3|)$, for otherwise the LHS is positive, while the RHS is negative. Moreover, the factors on the LHS are nonzero integers by $x\nmid a_3$ and $y\nmid a_3$. So there are finitely many possibilities for the factors on the LHS (namely they are integral divisors of the finitely many possible values of the RHS), hence also for the triple $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: For the above result to have application in primality testing, we need to explicitly determine a value $z_{min}$ as function of $a_3, a_2, a_1$ so that for all $z >z_{min}$, $xz+1$ is not a proper divisor of $P(z) $. From the last inequality of Case 2 of your proof, all solutions $(x, y, z)$ have $z<a_3^2 +2a_3+a_2m^2 - a_1a_3-1$ where $m=3$max$(|a_1|,|a_2|,|a_3|$). However the upper bound of $z$ in Case 1 is not clear.

Comment: Currently I am researching on the question : Given a prime $p$ and a positive integer $a$, Is there an efficient way of determining whether $sp+1$ is a proper divisor of $ap+1$ or at least can we find some forms of integers $a$ such that it can be efficiently determined whether $sp+1$ is a proper divisor of $ap+1$. I have found a few such integers $a$, I'll share the idea in another post to see if the idea can be generalized.

Comment: @DavidJones: In Case 1, the nonzero integer $r$ can be explicitly determined as a polynomial of $(a_1,a_2,a_3,x)$ by running the division algorithm for $a_3^2 P(Z)$ and $xZ+1$. As $x$ is a divisor of $a_3$, we get an explicit upper bound for $r$ in terms of $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, which is then an upper bound for $z$ as well.